# Dynamic Dependent / Triple Related selects in ColdFusion, third not holding first select

Tags: drop-down-menu, coldfusion

First of all I’m not only brand new to SO, but I’m also brand new to any kind of web programming, so total newb, thanks for your help and patience! So, zero previous experience with HTML, ColdFusion, SQL, SQL Server,  etc, so anything I’ve picked up I’ve learned in the past 2 weeks.

I am trying to make 3 dynamic dependent dropdown menus (triple related selects) in ColdFusion, that ultimately end up opening a map in another .CFM page. The dropdowns are populated from one single table in SQL Server.
I’ve done a lot of research (here on SO and elsewhere) and I have a method that is mostly working, but it has an issue and I would love help in figuring out why one thing isn’t working.  I am using a .CFC to query the database for the info for each dropdown menu and I’m trying to make each dependent on the previous, and then in the .CFM I’m using “bind”.  Here's my code for both the CFC and CFM:

CFC (named GettingData):

```
<cfcomponent displayname="GetStuff" hint="Getting data on cruises from database">
   <!---GET ARRAY OF TRIBUTARIES--->
   <cffunction name="getData" access="remote"  returntype="query" hint="Get data for first select">
      <!---define variables--->
      <cfset var data="tributary">
      <!---Run the query for tributaries--->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
         SELECT distinct Tributary
         FROM df_cruises
         ORDER BY Tributary
      </cfquery>
      <!---and return it--->
      <cfreturn data>
   </cffunction>
   <!---Get DATES by tributary--->
   <cffunction name="getDates" access="remote" returntype="query" 
      hint="Get cruise dates by tributary for select dropdown">
      <cfargument name="Tributary" type="any" required="no">
      <!---Define variables--->
      <cfset var data="CruiseDate">
      <!---Run query to get Date Data--->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
         SELECT *, CruiseDate AS date <!---this gets date to display correctly in dropdown--->
         FROM df_cruises
         WHERE Tributary='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'<!---single quotes for SQL Server--->
         ORDER BY CruiseDate desc
      </cfquery>
      <!---And return it--->
      <cfreturn data>
   </cffunction>
   <!---getting the html file based on the cruisedate selection--->
   <cffunction name="getmapname" access="remote" returntype="query" 
      hint="Get html file by tributary and cruisedate for dropdown select">
      <cfargument name="Tributary" type="any" required="no">
      <cfargument name="mapfile" type="any" required="no">
      <!---Define variables--->
      <cfset var data="">
      <cfset var data="">
      <!---Get file html Data--->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
         SELECT CruiseDate, Tributary, File_html
         FROM df_cruises
         WHERE CruiseDate='#ARGUMENTS.mapfile#'AND Tributary='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'AND File_html<>'notsampled'
      </cfquery>
      <!---And return it--->
      <cfreturn data>
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

CFM (named DropdownDisplay):

```
<cfparam name="url.File_html" default = '2'>
<cfform name="CruiseChoose" action="mapdisplayv3.cfm" method="post">
   <table align="center" bgcolor="orange">
      <tr>
         <th colspan="2">
            <font size="+1">First Select a Water Body, Then Choose Cruise Date</font>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <br/>
            Tributary/Water Body:<br />
            <cfselect name="Tributary" 
               bind="cfc:GettingData.getData()"
               display="Tributary"
               value="Tributary"
               bindonload="true"
               multiple="no"
               size="6" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <br />
            Cruise Dates:<br />
            <cfselect name="CruiseDate"
               bind="cfc:GettingData.getDates({Tributary})"
               bindonload="false"
               type="link"
               display="date"
               value="CruiseDate"
               multiple="no"
               size="6"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <br>
            Map Links:<br />
            <cfselect name="link"
               bind="cfc:GettingData.getmapname({CruiseDate},{Tributary})"
               bindonload="false"
               type="any"
               display="File_html"
               value="File_html"
               multiple="no"
               size="3"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <br />
            </form>
            <!--- submit button ---> 
            <cfoutput>  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Selected Maps" alt="View Map Selection Button"><br></cfoutput>
            <!--- Reset button. ---> 
            <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Selections" alt="Clear Selections Button">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</cfform>
</html>
```

The first dropdown is pulling a list of tributaries, and when a ‘Tributary’ is chosen the second dropdown correctly populates the list of ‘CruiseDates’ when they were sampled.  The third dropdown is supposed to populate with the ‘File_html’ from the table which becomes a link to open an image map of data on another CFM. (This isn’t my ultimate goal, this was me baby-stepping my way there.)

The issue I am having is that the third dropdown does not seem to be holding the dependency to the first dropdown selection (Tributary), so when a CruiseDate is selected where 2 tributaries happened to be sampled on the same date both of those File_html names show up in the third dropdown (screenshot):
In the CFC, in “getmapname” function, I’ve tried using 2 arguments (which I saw used somewhere online) so that I can reuse the argument  (along with the cfargument name="mapfile") so that in the last query I can do the following:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
    SELECT CruiseDate, Tributary, File_html
    FROM df_cruises
    WHERE CruiseDate='#ARGUMENTS.mapfile#' AND Tributary='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'
    AND File_html<>'notsampled'
</cfquery>
```

This didn’t work. I get errors when I have 2 arguments, it only seems to allow 1.

Here's a screenshot of the third dropdown showing that, although 'Back River' is selected, it's pulling the File_html for 2 tributaries that were sampled on the same date: 
[image: screenshot of 3rd dropdown not holding 1st dropdown select]

I also started working on a javascript version but I’m stuck on that as well, and since this was so close I keep working on this method.  However, if it’s impossible to do triple related selects with this method I’ll have to move on!

Any help would be really wonderful, thank you! -B
(sorry for the long post, just trying to be thorough)

Comment: Nothing like starting with something difficult.  You say `The issue I am having is that the third dropdown does not seem to be holding the dependency to the first dropdown selection`.  If you have 3 selects, shouldn't the 3rd one depend on the 2nd instead of the first?

Comment: I know, right? Yes and no, I guess I want the third select to be dependent on both the first and second. So you choose a 'Tributary', then you choose the 'CruiseDate', and the third dropdown should populate with the 'File_html' link to the data for JUST that Tributary and CruiseDate, but right now it's populating with the links to whatever Tributaries were sampled on that date.

Comment: this is where I saw the use of 2 arguments, but I couldn't get it to work:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/886531?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What was the exact code you used and the full error message? You can assign more than one argument. However, you need to define both arguments in the cffunction, and pass the expected number of values into the bind. As an aside, once you get it working be sure to secure the queries with cfqueryparam to prevent sql injection. Also, while this is a good learning experience ... CF's ajax features are known to be a bit outdated and brittle. So you might consider using another library like jQuery instead. It is a bit more complex at first, but is a lot more robust.

Comment: Now it's not giving me an error message, but the problem still exists. The code I think I had before, and that I just tried again is this:
`<cffunction name="getmapname" access="remote" returntype="query">
<cfargument name="Tributary" type="any" required="no">
<cfargument name="mapfile" type="any" required="no">
<!---Define vars--->
<cfset var data="">
<!---Get file_html--->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
SELECT CruiseDate, Tributary, File_html FROM df_cruises
WHERE CruiseDate='#ARGUMENTS.mapfile#' AND Tributary='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#' AND File_html<>'notsampled'
</cfquery>`

Comment: (Edit) Thanks, can you [append that as an edit to the question?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36893740/edit). Hard to read that much code in the comments  :) Since it is ajax, the first place to look for errors in is your browser's javascript console, then check the CF error logs {cf_root}\logs.

Comment: sorry, that's messy, but all I did was add: `<cfargument name="Tributary" type="any" required="no">'` into the function named "getmapfile". And then in the query below that function in the WHERE I added: `AND Tributary='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'`

Comment: Just edited to add that second argument to the code, thanks!

Comment: (Edit) Looks like our posts clashed. It is not enough to just add an argument :). If the function is expecting two values... the bind must supply it with two values. So like I mentioned above, the cfselect bind must also pass two values to the cfc. Though again, check your javascript console for errors. That is the best tool for troubleshooting JS errors.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help, I'm muddling through trying these suggestions. Is it protocol to always change the code in the original post instead of putting code changes in the comments?  I tried what Leigh suggested (not sure if I did it correctly) and I'm getting an error of: "Bind failed, element not found: Tributary" and "window:global: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null (http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js, line 1272)".

Comment: I figured out how to check my "javascript console for errors" (thank you!) and this is what it says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null` and 
`...DropdownDisplay.cfm?cfdebug Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (You cannot specify more arguments to a CFC function than it declares.)`

Comment: (Edit) Strictly from the error message, either the function was not updated with multiple arguments or the changes were not detected. Try calling the functions in a browser first, where it is easier to spot errors. For example:  `http://yourservername/path/to/YourComponent.cfc?method=getmapname&mapfile=abc&TRIBUTARY=123`  *RE: always change the code* No, that is why I said "append" not overwrite. I do not know if it is a hard and fast rule, but IMO it is best to preserve context and append changes as "update 1", "update 2", etcetera.  As long as the thread does not turn into War and Peace ;-)

Comment: Edit:  *RE: instead of putting code changes in the comments* Missed that part. Well if the change is very relevant to the question asked or it is a more than say one line of code, it is better to append it to the question (not overwrite). So it is more visible.  Also, comments are considered temporary which can (and often do) disappear. I would not be at all surprised if this entire comment thread was deleted as "too chatty" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's help and patience, I got the 2 arguments to work and the 3rd dropdown is now only returning data that it should (ie. it's correctly bound to the selections from the first and second dropdowns). THANK YOU!
Here's the new code which works:

CFC:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="GetStuff" hint="Getting data on cruises from database">
   <!---GET ARRAY OF TRIBUTARIES--->
   <cffunction name="getData" access="remote"  returntype="query" hint="Get data for first select">
      <!---define variables--->
      <cfset var data="tributary">
      <!---Run the query for tributaries--->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
         SELECT distinct Tributary
         FROM df_cruises
         ORDER BY Tributary
      </cfquery>
      <!---and return it--->
      <cfreturn data>
   </cffunction>
   <!---Get DATES by tributary--->
   <cffunction name="getDates" access="remote" returntype="query" >
      <cfargument name="Tributary" type="any" required="no">
      <!---Define variables--->
      <cfset var data="CruiseDate">
      <!---Run query to get Date Data--->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
         SELECT *, CruiseDate AS date 
         FROM df_cruises
         WHERE Tributary=
         <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'>
         ORDER BY CruiseDate desc
      </cfquery>
      <!---And return it--->
      <cfreturn data>
   </cffunction>
   <!---getting the html file based on the CruiseDate selection--->
   <cffunction name="getmapname" access="remote" returntype="query" >
      <cfargument name="mapfile" type="any" required="no" default="">
      <cfargument name="Tributary" type="any" required="no" default="">
      <!---Define variables--->
      <cfset var data="">
      <!---Get file html Data--->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="mydatasource">
         SELECT CruiseDate, Tributary, File_html
         FROM df_cruises
         WHERE CruiseDate=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_date' value='#ARGUMENTS.mapfile#'> AND Tributary=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'> AND File_html<><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='notsampled'>
      </cfquery>
      <!---And return it--->
      <cfreturn data>
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

CFM:

```
<cfparam name="url.File_html" default = '2'>
<cfform name="CruiseChoose" action="mapdisplayv3.cfm" method="post">
   <table align="center" bgcolor="orange">
      <tr>
         <th colspan="2">
            <font size="+1">First Select a Water Body, Then Choose Cruise Date</font>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <br />
            Tributary/Water Body:<br />
            <cfselect name="Tributary" 
               bind="cfc:GettingData.getData()"
               display="Tributary"
               value="Tributary"
               bindonload="true"
               multiple="no"
               size="6" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <br />
            Cruise Dates:<br />
            <cfselect name="CruiseDate"
               bind="cfc:GettingData.getDates({Tributary})"
               bindonload="false"
               type="link"
               display="date"
               value="CruiseDate"
               multiple="no"
               size="6"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <br>
            Map Links:<br />
            <cfselect name="link"
               bind="cfc:GettingData.getmapname({CruiseDate}, {Tributary})"
               bindonload="false"
               type="any"
               display="File_html"
               value="File_html"
               multiple="no"
               size="3"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <br />
            </form>
            <!--- submit button ---> 
            <cfoutput>  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Selected Maps" alt="View Map Selection Button"><br></cfoutput>
            <!--- Reset button. ---> 
            <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Selections" alt="Clear Selections Button">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</cfform>
</html>
```

Comment: (Edit) Nice job. Did you mean to filter the third query on `CruiseDate='#ARGUMENTS.mapfile#'` only? Side note, do not forget to use cfqueryparam on *all* query parameters (sql injection protection) and give jQuery a look when you get a chance. It is *much* less brittle than the CF UI features in IMO :)

Comment: Since I don't know what you mean by filtering the query, probably not! I really have a meager understanding of all of this so far. I did take a stab at jQuery, I'll have to go back and try harder at that attempt, since that sounds like a better way to go. And thanks for the reminders for cfqueryparam, I'll add them in everywhere else before it's final.

Comment: Filtering, ie `WHERE` clause conditions that restrict which records the query returns :) Since the function accepts two arguments, I thought (perhaps wrongly) that you wanted the query to *only* return records that matched both the supplied CruiseDate and Tributary values. In which case, both arguments need to be included in the `WHERE` clause. Ignoring cfqueryparam and in psuedo-sql,  something like WHERE CruiseDate = '#arguments.nameOfFirstArgument#' and Tributary='#arguments.nameOfOtherArgument#'.

Comment: oh, yes! I have a paste error! I'll correct it, I do have both arguments in there! Nice catch :)

Comment: One more question - is it possible to get multiple selects for all dropdowns working with this method? Or should I switch to jQuery or something else?

Comment: Probably yes. Though you would need to modify the queries to use `WHERE Column IN (...)` instead of equals (single equality test only).

Answer (score 1):

Start with the query for your 2nd select.

```
 SELECT *, CruiseDate AS date <!---this gets date to display correctly in dropdown--->
         FROM df_cruises
         WHERE Tributary='#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#'<!---single quotes for SQL Server--->
         ORDER BY CruiseDate desc
```

I am going to assume that table df_cruises has a numeric PK named cruiseID.  Change the query to this:

```
 SELECT cruiseId
, CruiseDate AS date <!---this gets date to display correctly in dropdown--->
 FROM df_cruises
 WHERE Tributary= cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.Tributary#">
ORDER BY CruiseDate desc
```

Your bind for the 3rd select will resemble this:

```
bind="cfc:UsingBook.getmapname({cruiseId})"
```

And your final query is this:

```
SELECT CruiseDate, Tributary, File_html
FROM df_cruises
WHERE cruiseID = cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
value="#ARGUMENTS.cruiseID#>
AND File_html<>'notsampled'
```

Note the use of a query parameter for the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. First of all I realized I was referencing the wrong CFC in the code, so I corrected that (so your above code pastes should say 'GettingData' instead of 'UsingBook'). And yes, you are right there is a PK called "ID", so I followed your instructions using "ID" where you have "cruiseID". I get 2 binding errors: `error:bind: Bind failed for select box CruiseDate, columns matching the value or display attributes specified on the cfselect tag are not present in the query` and
`error:bind: Bind failed, element not found: ID`

Comment: I got rid of the first error by adding a * to the second query (luckily the table is small), and the second dropdown is working. But I'm still getting `error:bind: Bind failed, element not found: ID` and the third dropdown isn't populating.

Comment: Well you have the right approach now.  You just have to work through the details.  To help, you might want to test your cfc functions using coldfusion code only before trying them with javascript.  That way, if something goes wrong, you will at least know the function is ok.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll keep at it! I got this far already!